# JBossAS 6 & Riftsaw: "No context found for request" when loading WSDL

Tags: jboss, soap

I'm evaluating the use of Riftsaw and have been following the Getting Started guide:

http://docs.jboss.org/riftsaw/releases/2.3.0.Final/gettingstartedguide/html/examples.html#d0e240

I've installed JBossAS 6, JBoss ESB 4.10 and Riftsaw 2.3.0 on my server (let's call it server1, with IP 10.0.0.1 a FQDN of server1.domain.com) and can access the admin console fine from both server1 and my development PC. I have deployed the "Hello World" quickstart example and I can view the WSDL from both computers in a web browser from server1:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl. On server1, I can also use localhost:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl *(please assume URLs have http:// prefix – as a new user I'm restricted to 2 hyperlinks)*.

I am trying to use soapUI to test invocation of the service. I create a new sopaUI project, enter server1:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl for "Initial WSDL/WADL" and I receive an "Unexpected element: CDATA" error. Looking at the http log, soapUI receives HTML with the following data:

> ## 404 Not Found
>
> No context found for request

This happens on both my development PC **and server1 itself**.

If I create a soapUI project on server1 using localhost:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl, it successfully processes the WSDL and creates a sample request. However, the endpoint for this request (in the WSDL) is SERVER1:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS and if I try and submit it, the "404" data is returned. Using soapUI, I manually edited the endpoint to be localhost:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS and it works, returning the expected response.

I have also received the "404" page when doing the following:

- Opening server1.domain.com:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl from my dev PC in a web browser
- Opening 10.0.0.1:8080/Quickstart_hello_worldWS?wsdl from my dev PC or from server1 in a web browser

So my question is, why is soapUI only able to read the WSDL and send a request using "localhost" and how can I do that using the servers DNS name?

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the HTTP GET requests sent by IE, Firefox and soapUI and found that soapUI was sending the request to the IPv4 address of server1, whereas IE and Firefox were sending it to the IPv6 address. I set the "network.dns.disableIPv6" to TRUE in Firefox's "about:config" and Firefox then received the same 404 error as soapUI.

Up until now, I had run JBoss bound to all network interfaces:

```
.\run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

I managed to work around this problem by binding JBoss to the IPv4 address of server1:

```
.\run.bat -b 10.0.0.1
```